# Variable expansion in subprocess.Popen

Tags: bash, variables, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to run a shell command within a python 3 script and use raw_input to get that info.

I've seen a few remedies to my answer around, and haven't tried them all. I'm more curious to find why I'm getting this result rather than what I was expecting.

Here is my test Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

iface = "en0"

iocmd = "ifconfig %s | grep netmask | awk {'print $2'}" % (iface)
ip = subprocess.Popen(iocmd , shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print (ip)
```

This is all fine an dandy ( I know shell=True is a security issue, but for now I'm more interested in making the code work), but when I run this, instead of it outputting the IP, I'm getting:

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x1020d85f8>
```

I'm wondering why this is returning the status as opposed to the command output?

I've also tried:

```
ip = subprocess.Popen(['ifconfig ' + iface + ' | grep netmask | awk {\'print $4\'}'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and gotten the same result...

Any ideas how to streamline this? I will eventually move to a more secure method, but this is the only instance of a subprocess call I'm using as I need to get the IP and netmask and want to use native modules.

Thanks for any input!

Chris

Comment: `shell=True` isn't necessarily a security issue if you are in control of all the params being passed.

Comment: Yeah, the doc says if you're using variables to pass in your parameters it could lead to shell injection and arbitrary command execution. Is there a way to secure raw_input before passing it to a function like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `ip` is a`Popen` object. It has a `stdout` attribute that you can `read()` from

```
print(ip.stdout.read())
```

Comment: Thanks! I like that better than the .communicate function I was using. 

That outputs:

`b'192.168.0.100\n'`

What do the **b** and **\n** indicate?

Comment: The `b` is a prefix that means that the literal is bytes (rather than unicode). `\n` is a newline character

Comment: Just FYI for anyone who want's to strip the byte and newline indicator you can use this:

`print (subprocess.check_output(iocmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True),end="")`